# Apple park arview demo -view overlap issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation

I am using apple pARK demo for live camera feed with nearby places-of-interest.

**Problem**

```
 All the view are overlapped each other.
```

**Code**

[image]

```
-(void)getNewDataFromLocation:(CLLocation*)currentLocation
{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool =[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *strURL =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%d&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDst4th70R2y2kaExv10UIr7cxS3KQUejs",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,RADIUS];

    NSDictionary *dictPlace = [JSONHandler parseJSONDataFromURL:strURL PostString:nil withHTTPRequestType:@"POST"];     
    NSMutableArray *arrPalces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictPlace objectForKey:@"results"]];

    NSMutableArray *placesOfInterest = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[arrPalces count]];
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrPalces count]; i++) {

        NSDictionary *dictPlace = [arrPalces objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *dictLocation = [[dictPlace objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"];

        CLLocation *tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dictLocation valueForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue] longitude:[[dictLocation valueForKey:@"lng"]doubleValue]]; 

        double dist = [tempLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

        NSString *strDist = @"";

        if (dist>1000) {
            strDist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f KM",MILES_FOR_METERS(dist)];
        }
        else{
            strDist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f Meters",dist];
        }

        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        label.opaque = NO;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.1f blue:0.1f alpha:0.5f];
        //label.center = CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f);
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.text = [dictPlace objectForKey:@"name"];
        CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);

        UILabel *labelDist = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        labelDist.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        labelDist.opaque = NO;
        labelDist.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.1f blue:0.1f alpha:0.5f];

        labelDist.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        labelDist.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [labelDist setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        labelDist.text = strDist;
        size = [labelDist.text sizeWithFont:labelDist.font];
        labelDist.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, label.frame.size.height, size.width, size.height);

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height*2)];
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        view.center = CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f);

        [view addSubview:labelDist];
        [view addSubview:label];

        PlaceOfInterest *poi = [PlaceOfInterest placeOfInterestWithView:view at:tempLocation];
        [placesOfInterest insertObject:poi atIndex:i];
    }   
    [arView setPlacesOfInterest:placesOfInterest];  
    [pool release]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];
}
```

**DrawRect method**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (placesOfInterestCoordinates == nil) {
        return;
    }

    mat4f_t projectionCameraTransform;
    multiplyMatrixAndMatrix(projectionCameraTransform, projectionTransform, cameraTransform);

    int i = 0;
    for (PlaceOfInterest *poi in [placesOfInterest objectEnumerator]) {
        vec4f_t v;
        multiplyMatrixAndVector(v, projectionCameraTransform, placesOfInterestCoordinates[i]);

        float x = (v[0] / v[3] + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
        float y = (v[1] / v[3] + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
        if (v[2] < 0.0f) {
            poi.view.frame=CGRectMake(abs(poi.view.frame.origin.x), abs(poi.view.frame.origin.y), poi.view.frame.size.width, poi.view.frame.size.height);
            poi.view.center = CGPointMake(abs(x*self.bounds.size.width), abs(self.bounds.size.height-y*self.bounds.size.height));
            poi.view.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            poi.view.hidden = YES;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use Pins to indicate the place and to click user can see location details. The way you are doing, IMHO there is not a probable solution available.

Comment: but if i will take a pin , then  it will also be overlap. is there any way if i will fix the near by places count and display the view at fixed position in the arview.

Comment: If locations are at the exact same location, then only they will overlap. At a certain level of zoom they will definitely be separated.

Comment: But how can i manage zoom level?

Comment: did you find some solution?